# How to implement abstract classes over mulitple inheritances?

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, abc

I have a question on multi level inheritance.
I am trying to write classes of the form:

```py
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod
import numpy as np

### Parent class
class A(ABC):
  @abstractmethod
  def eval(self, x: np.ndarray) -> np.ndarray:
    pass

  @abstractmethod
  def func(self, x: np.ndarray) -> None:
    pass

### 1. Inheritance
class B1(A):
  def eval(self, x: np.ndarray) -> np.ndarray:
    #do something here
    return np.zeros(5)

  @abstractmethod
  def func(self, x: np.ndarray) -> None:
    pass

class B2(A):
  def eval(self, x: np.ndarray) -> np.ndarray:
    #do something different here
    return np.zeros(10)

  @abstractmethod
  def func(self, x: np.ndarray) -> None:
    pass

### 2. Inheritance
class C1(B1):
  def func(self, x: np.ndarray) -> None:
    print('child1.1')

class C2(B1):
  def func(self, x: np.ndarray) -> None:
    print('child1.2')

class C3(B2):
  def func(self, x: np.ndarray) -> None:
    print('child2.1')

c1 = C1()
c2 = C2()
c3 = C3()
```

I am not planning on instantiating `A` `B1` or `B2`.
My question is, if this is the correct way to go about this in python? I want to make it clear that `Bx` are still abstract classes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its quite simple. If class `A` defines some abstract methods, then any other class which inherits from `A` also inherits these methods. Not need to reimplement as abstract methods.

In your case your `Bx` classes only need their specialised implementations of `eval()`. They don't need `func()` since they already inherit them.

Comment: Thank you! Another question: Should I inherit the `ABC` meta class also e.g. `class B1(A, ABC)` to make it clear that `B1` is still an abstract class? I am looking for the most maintainable way to go about this.

Comment: I wouldn't bother. You can call `B1` and `B2` out as being abstract in your documentation, but the inability to instantiate `B1` or `B2` will make it obvious they are abstract.

Comment: okay, thank you for the quick answer!